# Trying to get property of non-object laravel plz

Tags: php, linux, laravel

@php
$package_banner_data=DB::table('accm_sys_media')->where('media_type','=',5)->where(AccmId,'=',$result['accm_sys_detail']->AccmId)->get();
@endphp

error:
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'AccmId' of non-object

application is developed in laravel

please help

Comment: Is `$result['accm_sys_detail']` an object?  What is it?

Comment: How to check that, I have very limited knowledge with respect to this..

Comment: If you're not familiar with how to debug PHP code (in Laravel or otherwise) then now is a good time to pause what you're building and start practicing that.  Debugging is a core fundamental skill of software development.  In this case your debugging goal is to observe the runtime values of your variables, which you can do by using a step debugger or by outputting them somewhere that you can see the result, such as to the page or to a file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error surely comes from the line  `...$result['accm_sys_detail']->AccmId ...` You are trying to get the AccmId property of $result['accm_sys_detail'] object.
Verify that the $result['accm_sys_detail'] is an object. You can use

`var_dump($result['accm_sys_detail'])`

to see if the variable stores an object type.
Or use `gettype()` function to find out if the variable is carrying and object.

Comment: I am getting the same error for all .php files